# Magento 2: Errors on running setup:di:compile after upgrade from Magento version 2.3.0 to 2.4.3:

Tags: magento2, error, upgrade, magento2.4.3

I am getting this error after upgrading Magento version 2.3.0 to 2.4.3.

```
Repositories code generation... 1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% < 1 sec 123.0 MiBClass 'Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Query\Builder\Match' not found#0 /var/www/html/crimsonav230/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include()
#1 /var/www/html/crimsonav230/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call()
#4 /var/www/html/crimsonav230/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(134): class_exists()
#5 /var/www/html/crimsonav230/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClass()
#6 /var/www/html/crimsonav230/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(87): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract()
#7 /var/www/html/crimsonav230/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/RepositoryGenerator.php(61): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList()
#8 /var/www/html/crimsonav230/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\RepositoryGenerator->doOperation()
#9 /var/www/html/crimsonav230/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php(216): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process()
#10 /var/www/html/crimsonav230/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute()
#11 /var/www/html/crimsonav230/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#12 /var/www/html/crimsonav230/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#13 /var/www/html/crimsonav230/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#14 /var/www/html/crimsonav230/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
#15 /var/www/html/crimsonav230/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#16 {main}
```

I am unable to find any solution. please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code have dependencies on `Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\*` classes.

Support of Mysql search adapter was deprecated in 2.3 and removed in 2.4.

Please review your code/customization and remove this dependencies.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\* classes and it worked.